# reactjs Testing with Enzyme , TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

Please Help,
I have a small demo that i created.
the code works great in the browser but fails in tests.

here is what the code does:

- render two links: "HOME" and "MODELER" as part of a `Navigation` component.
- use `react-router` to implement the required routes: `/` to render `HomePage`
  and `/modeler` to render `ModelerPage`
- The `HomePage` component should simply render `<h1>Home</h1>`
  **- The `ModelerPage` component should render `<h1>Modeler</h1>` as well as an initialized modeler
  instance which is rendered into a container after the `<h1>`.** By 'modeler' i refer to the library bpmn.js (docs can be found here: https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js)

here is the link to the entire application and working demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jr89309w9

my problem is that when i try to load the modeler while in test, it fails with error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
```

here is my modeler component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import BpmnJS from "bpmn-js/dist/bpmn-modeler.development.js";
import "bpmn-js/dist/assets/diagram-js.css";
import "bpmn-js/dist/assets/bpmn-font/css/bpmn-embedded.css";
class ModelerPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.viewer = new BpmnJS()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const cont = document.querySelector('.container')
    this.viewer.attachTo(".container");
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.viewer.detach();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Modeler</h1>
        <div className="container"> </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ModelerPage;
```

and here are my tests:

```
import "../jest-setup";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import React from "react";
import App from "./App";

it("renders an app with 2 routes, home and modeler page", async () => {

  const wrapper = mount(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/"]} initialIndex={0}>
      <App />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
  const HomeTitle = <h1>Home</h1>;
  const ModelerTitle = <h1>Modeler</h1>;


  // Home title is rendered
  expect(wrapper.contains(HomeTitle)).toEqual(true);

  // When clicking the /modeler link
  wrapper.find('[href="/modeler"]').simulate("click", { button: 0 });

  // Modeler title is rendered
  expect(wrapper.contains(ModelerTitle)).toEqual(true);


  // Modeler container is rendered   
  expect(wrapper.html()).toMatch(/.bjs-container/);

});
```

the BpmJS library is loaded in the `componentDidMount()` so the DOM should be ready, but the `enzyme.mount()` is not really recreating the DOM.

how should these kind of components be tested ?

Answer (score 0):

the fix is easy:

just add a constructor and instantiate : `React.createRef();`
like so:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
    this.viewer =  new BpmnJS()
  }
```

and the element, instead of using a `className` use `ref={this.myRef}` like so:

```
    <div ref={this.myRef}> </div>
```

this should do it